# Angular Bootstrap Datepicker Gives us date object . I want it as Date

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6

I want my date as "Wed Aug 07 2019 16:42:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
but I'm getting { year: 1789, month: 7, day: 14 } From ngbDatepicker
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Put your code here or.. in stackblitz

Comment: I referred this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnv11x?file=app/datepicker-popup.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to convert the object into a date...which you can do in your `select` method as following:

relevant **TS**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html'
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {
  model;
  convertedDate;
  select(d){
    console.log(d);
    this.convertedDate = new Date(d.year, d.month, d.day);
  }

}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class="input-group ">
    <input id="datepicker" class="form-control col-7" [(ngModel)]="model" placeholder="" ngbDatepicker #date="ngbDatepicker" required (ngModelChange)="select(model)" pattern="[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary picto-calender" (click)="date.toggle()" type="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>

selected Date: {{convertedDate}}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnv11x-dooxee)

Comment: I want a permanent Solution, I cant write this for each and every date. When I get Data again I have to parse date in object and assign to model

Comment: You want to avoid, conversion, than you'd have to use something other than "ngbd-datepicker"... probably a normal HTML datepicker; else you gotta convert